# How to train Watson application using Alchemy Language API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi, alchemy

I have used the Alchemy Language API demo:

https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/

...to deploy on Bluemix dashboard, and now it is successfully built and deployed.

Now I am not sure how to make system aware of taxonomy, keywords, entities etc. Basically I need help in training the Watson app. Please let me know if I should do this from Bluemix. I have read that IBM Watson Knowledge Studio provides "Human Annotation" Page where the training data can be uploaded.

Now I want to know the steps to train the system. Where can I get the training data for Watson app? Please help. This is the first time I am executing this app.

Here is the link : https://alchemylanguage-nodejs-bludev-1532.mybluemix.net/

Thanks in advance!!

Prerna

Comment: I am not sure you can train a model using alchemy API. AFAIK you can only use their model (trained using wikipedia) but I may be wrong.

Comment: HI, May be I used wrong word "train" for AlchemyAPI. I want to know the steps how to use a reference to analyze a content. Where should I add wikipedia URL ?

Comment: Alchemy uses (I think) a engine that receives as input text. Then it parses the text, try to identify entities and verbs etc and try to infer the meanings of the text. For these meanings, it tries to find concepts, keywords etc based on the data available from the Wikipedia. So for example, you may ask Alchemy Text to extract entities from the phrase "IBM is an american company" and it may return to you concepts from the wikipedia such as "IBM", "US", "Company", with some score (confidence level) for example. So I think there's no way to tell Alchemy API where to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can't train the [AlchemyLanguage](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/alchemy-language.html) models that are being used to recognize `taxonomy`, `entities` or `keywords` but, You can get customized results for `entities` and `typed relations` using the [IBM Watson Knowledge Studio](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/knowledge-studio.html).

Once you create a [custom model](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/alchemylanguage/customizing.shtml) using Knowledge Studio, look at the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/?curl#typed-relations) to learn how to call the API with your model in different languages.